# SAS proc sql disqualify observations that have already been merged

Tags: sql, sas

I am merging two datasets using 5 criteria sets, with the condition that if a match is created under criteria set number *n*, then those observations are disqualified from matching under any other criteria set *x > n*. For example, if a merge is successful under the first criteria set between dataset 1:observation 10 and dataset2:observation15, then those two observations are not eligible to be merged under any of the later criteria (second, third, fourth, fifth).

My method thus far has been to add a flag variable to the table created by the merge and then merge that table back to both parent datasets, and then for the next criteria set I require that the flag variable be missing. However, I have new datasets that are large and this method fails because of an "out of resources" error. It is simple but very long sorry.  Thank in advance for reading.

Example of current code for the first two criteria:

```
* Initialize parent datasets
data work.parentdata1;
set lib.parentdata1;
run;

data work.parentdata2;
set lib.parentdata2;
run;

***************;
*Criteria set 1;
***************;
proc sql;
create table match_1 as
select *
from parentdata1 o, parentdata2 t
    where o.variable_A = t.variable_a
    and o.variable_B= t.variable_b
;
quit;

* Results dataset (to be used for later analysis);
data work.match_1;
    set match_1;
    match_quality = 1;
run;

* Dataset for merge with parent dataset 1;
data work.mergematched_1;
    set match_1;
    match_dummy = 1;
run;

* sort matched table by parent dataset 1 id to prepare for parent merge;
proc sort data = work.mergematched_1;
    by id1;
run;

* merge matched observations back to parent dataset 1 to disqualify from      future criteria sets;
data work.parentdata1_a;
    merge work.parentdata1 work.mergematched_1;
    by id1;
run;

*sort matched table by parent dataset 2 id to prepare for parent merge;
proc sort data = work.mergematched_1;
    by id2;
run;

*merge matched observations back to parent dataset 2 to disqualify from   future criteria sets;
data work.parentdata2_a;
    merge work.parentdata2 work.mergematched_2;
    by id2;
run;
***************;
*Criteria set 2;
***************;
proc sql;
create table match_2 as
select *
from parentdata1 o, parentdata2 t
where o.match_dummy = . and t.match_dummy = .
and o.variable_X = t.variable_x
and o.variable_Y= t.variable_y
;
quit;

* Results dataset (to be used for later analysis);
data work.match_2;
set match_2;
match_quality = 2;
run;

* Dataset for merge with parent dataset 1a;
data work.mergematched_2;
set match_2;
match_dummy = 1;
run;

* sort matched table by parent dataset 1a id to prepare for parent merge;
proc sort data = work.mergematched_2;
by id1;
run;

* merge matched observations back to parent dataset 1a to disqualify from      future criteria sets;
data work.parentdata1_b;
merge work.parentdata1_a work.mergematched_2;
by id1;
run;

*sort matched table by parent dataset 2a id to prepare for parent merge;
proc sort data = work.mergematched_2;
by id2;
run;

*merge matched observations back to parent dataset 2a to disqualify from future criteria sets;
data work.parentdata2_b;
merge work.parentdata2_a work.mergematched_2;
by id2;
run;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you join in PROC SQL and not in datastep?

Comment: No particular reason. Proc sql seemed to be the preferred merging method among the resources I came across when I first started the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only using 3 or 4 values in the merge try dropping all other variables and keep only those for the merging and then merge back in all the other results at the end.

I also don't know if you you need both match_1 and merged_match1 as it doesn't appear to change the file except adding another variable. Avoid creating temporary datasets as much as possible if you're running out of space.

I think you can also combine a few steps into one like the following, which is the first four procs/data steps under Criteria 1.

```
proc sql;
create table match_1 as
select *, 1 as match_quality, 1 as match_dummy
from parentdata1 o
inner join parentdata2 t
on o.variable_A = t.variable_a
and o.variable_B= t.variable_b
order by id1
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  2 comments:I am testing your method but the proc sql giving a warning that all variables already exist on file match_x for all criteria > 1. FYI the criteria are similar, for example criteria 1 is an exact date match with several other variables matching and then criteria 2 is the same except the date is allowed to fall within +/- 5 days instead of exact match.

Comment: Second comment/question: Will using 'on' instead of 'where' still work when I need variables to be missing rather than equal to its counterpart in the other dataset. e.g. match_dummy must be missing from both parent datasets. So can i simply add "and o.match_dummy = . and t.match_dummy = ." before "order by id1"?

Comment: Re Comment #1 - This query would need to be repeated for each criteria creating a new table, the same as your code above.  Re Comment 2, yes you should be able to add the constraints or you could add a where clause as well.

Comment: If you're criteria is as in Comment #1, i.e. exact match and then within a few days it might be worth using a case statement instead to do the match but you don't give enough details about the actual problem in the questions to suggest more than than.